# Background image has lines in Safari?

Tags: css, background-image, safari

I have a background image on a website that doesn't want to work properly in Safari.

Here's what it looks like in Safari:
[image: Safari<br />]

And here's what it should look like, and what it does look like in Firefox and Chrome:
[image: Firefox and Chrome]

Does anyone know what's going on here, why it's doing this, and how I can fix it?

**edit**
The code that's adding the background image is as follows:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../imgaes/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

**edit 2**
The body tag has the following styling:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: show your code in jsfiddle.net or code

Comment: It's just basic CSS to the body tag. I've added the code in my question.

Comment: Can I see the actual image you are using?

Comment: Does the body have any wide or height set using CSS or a `display`-attribute?

Comment: @Sam The image is the same as I have shown you in the question, only bigger.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Nope, however I should have mentioned the body does have overflow-x set to hidden, and overflow-y set to scroll.

Comment: Seems to me like there is some vertical `background-size` set anywhere for Safari…

Comment: Can you recreate this problem in jsfiddle? How big is the background image?

Comment: @feeela There's no background-size set in the CSS anywhere.

Comment: @Richard Hedges Might be, but if you shrink the picture vertically while maintaining the horizontal size the result looks like what you have posted as Safari-screenshot. Check the heights of the `HTML` and `BODY` elements.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I tried, doing exactly what I've done on the site. For some reason the image isn't showing at all in Chrome or Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/3SxUx/

Comment: @feeela Oh my apologies, I see what you mean now. I'll dig around for any heights being set, but I'm pretty sure there isn't anything.

Comment: The fiddle works pretty fine in Safari (using 6.0).

Comment: I've tested this with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3SxUx/6 In Chromium the response to the load from imgur.com is "403 Forbidden" and in Firefox the request isn't send at all. The image is loaded in Opera, but it doesn't send a referrer to imgur.com and the `Accept`-header (`Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1`) is different to the Chromium one (`Accept:*/*`). Have you tried that setup with the image stored at the same domain?

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry I was linking a different file. I've linked the proper file now and it's doing the same thing it's doing for me in the site: http://jsfiddle.net/3bPgs/

Comment: Still works fine in Safari 6 and 5.1. Are you using Safari on a MAC or PC?

Comment: I'm using a Mac. On the latest version of Mountain Lion.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Just thought I'd let you know as well, I'm using Safari 6.0.1

Comment: Hm, I've updated my system to OS X 10.7.5 with Safari 6.0.1 and it's still working. That's strange.

Comment: I've just recreated the background image and it works fine. No idea what was wrong with the other file as it was working fine for you. I asked someone else to try on Safari on another Mac and they had the same problem. Very odd problem, but resolved with the new image.

Comment: Seems that the original image file was corrupt. Is this a high res MacBook Pro that you're using?

Comment: I can't understand why it would be corrupt if it worked on Firefox, Chrome and Opera. I'm using a Mac Mini (originally a server).

Comment: I had a similar thing sometime ago using the "Export for web and devices"-feature in Photoshop. Creating it again solved it for me, too

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but have you tried exporting it as a progressive jpeg? Safari seems to do funny things with "optimized" jpeg's, at least in iPad...

Comment: I've never tried that. Recreating the image solved the problem but I will take a look into what you suggested - it might give me a better understanding of where the problem came from. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the background image solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't offering much information of what exactly is going on, I would suggest putting some content in the body tag, because I think that Safari interprets the code so that your body has a height of 0px, that why it only repeats a really small part of your background image over and over again, you could either put a `min-height: 100%` into your body's CSS Code or as I said before try to insert some content in there.

Comment: The page had content, I just took a screenshot of a small portion of the background. Recreating the image solved this.